# Visualforce redirection with Site Path in Sites

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites

I've a Hyperlink formula field in an object like `'/apex/testPage?id=xxxx'`
When I'll click, this will go an open `'www.domain.force.com/apex/testPage?id=xxxx'`

I want to redirect same link in Sites to

> 'www.domain.force.com/**SITE_PATH**/apex/testPage?id=xxxx'

I wanted a SitePath to be prepend in following formula outcome -

`HYPERLINK('/apex/testPage?id=xxxx')` if in sites, otherwise as `/apex/testPage?id=xxxx`.

I am able to achieve this as -

```
HYPERLINK(
        LEFT(
                $Api.Partner_Server_URL_260,
                FIND('/services',$Api.Partner_Server_URL_260)
            )
        +'apex/testPage?id=xxx
    )
```

How we can achieve this

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear exactly which one you'll want to use to get the proper SITE_PATH as I'm uncertain of the context you're asking your question. All the different variations on the usage of the `$SITE` variables are explained on [this page of the Visualforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_site.htm) and there are many different ones you could use depending on the context.

Comment: I wanted a SitePath to be prepend in following formula outcome -
 HYPERLINK('/apex/testPage?id=xxxx') if in sites, otherwise as '/apex/testPage?id=xxxx'. I am able to achieve this as -
 HYPERLINK(LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_260, FIND( '/services', $Api.Partner_Server_URL_260))+'/apex/testPage?id=xxxx')